# Aggregating test results in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I've got a `Jenkinsfile` that invokes multiple sub-jobs via calls to `build job: ...`. Each of those sub-jobs runs a bunch of unit tests. Is there some way to collect all of those test results and make them part of the test results for the job that's invoking them? Essentially if I have 3 jobs, with 10 tests each, I'd like the result of this to have 30 test results. I thought perhaps `propagate` might do this, but it does not.

Answer (score 0):

You can archive build test results as artifacts and copy them into your main job using `copyArtifact` build step provided by a [Copy Artifact plugin](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/copyartifact/).

No-brainer example of main job Jenkinsfile:

```
build 'sub-job'    
node('master') {
    copyArtifacts projectName: 'sub-job', filter: 'results.xml', selector: lastCompleted()
    junit 'results.xml' // or whatever you use to publish test results
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the build step documentation

> propagate (optional)
>
> If set, then if the downstream build is anything but successful (blue
>   ball), this step fails. If disabled, then this step succeeds even if
>   the downstream build is unstable, failed, etc.; use the result
>   property of the return value as needed.

The thing that could work though is [Copy Artifact Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Copy+Artifact+Plugin)

```
stages {
     stage('Copy Archive') {
         steps {
             script {
                 step ([$class: 'CopyArtifact',
                 projectName: 'Create_archive',
                 filter: "packages/infra*.zip",
                 target: 'Infra']);
             }
         }
     }
```

Just be sure to filter for reports.